# What object receives #puts in my Crystal programs?

Tags: crystal-lang

In this basic Crystal program:

```
class Greeter
  def greet(person)
    puts "Hello, #{person}!"
  end
end
```

Who is the receiver of `#puts`? Is it `self`?

- If so, why can't I find a definition for it anywhere?
- If not, who is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, oddly, is nobody! At least not in the Ruby sense.

The [Crystal docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/everything_is_an_object.html) make the claim that everything is an object, but there's a slight cheat when it comes to these "top-level" methods.

Unlike Ruby, which puts everything "top-level" into the `Kernel` module, Crystal has the concept of a ["Top Level Namespace"](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.19.3/toplevel.html), where methods like `puts`, `gets`, `raise`, etc. live.

It doesn't appear to have an identifier associated with it, so you can't inspect/introspect it to find out what exists.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a somewhat old question, but I just started playing around with Crystal.

In Ruby the top level object is called `main`, is an instance of class `Object` and mixes in the `Kernel` module.

```
self
#=> main
self.class
#=> Object
self.class.ancestors
#=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

On the other hand the Crystal top level seems to be what the documentation refers to as "[The Program](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/the_program.html)", but it seems there's no way to programmatically access that: evaluating `self` at the top-level gives you the error `"there's no self in this scope"`. For the same reason you can't call `inspect` without an explicit receiver, since it will just tell you that there's no local variable or method by that name.

I guess the main hint is that the documentation for "[Top Level Namespace]" [2](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.19.4/toplevel.html)" lists no files in the "Defined In" section which generally lists the classes that define an object.

In short it seems the Crystal developers opted to keep the top level inaccessible, instead of the slightly weird [object/class hybrid](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/) that `main` is in Ruby.